# iterate over rows in dataframe, and if a value is > #, output a different row in the same column

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Imagine I have a dataframe of 100 columns that represent test subjects and 201 rows. The first row contains an ID that tells what group a test subject came from, the other rows are a measurement of gene expression. I would like to row by row and test each of the 200 values for the gene, measuring whether they were >= 5. If they are not, I would like to output the id in row1 corresponding to the low value

```
      subj1  subj2  subj3 ...
group  Dis    CNT   Dis
gene1   12     0     10
gene2   4      3     5
gene3   100   105    99
```

So here the output would be

```
gene1 CNT 
gene2 Dis, CNT
Gene3
```

Or even better, if it could output a running tally of the missingness in the groups:

```
       Dis CNT 
gene1  0    1
gene2  1    1
gene3  0    0
```

Im still pretty new to R, but I would like to resist the temptation to go and write this in perl. I feel like the task should be pretty siple. any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the first row, convert the type of columns with `type.convert`, loop over the row with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1`, subset the data with a logical expression and use that to get the corresponding first row, and `paste` them together, and if needed the named vector is converted to a two column data.frame with `stack`

```
out <- stack(apply(type.convert(df1[-1,], as.is = TRUE), 1, 
     function(x) toString(unlist(df1[1,])[x < 5])))[2:1]
```

-output

```
out
#   ind   values
#1 gene1      CNT
#2 gene2 Dis, CNT
#3 gene3
```

If we need to create a count column, remove the characters other than the `,` with `gsub` and get the count of `,` with `nchar` add 1 to it

```
out$cnt <- nchar(gsub("[^,]+", "", out$values)) + 1
out$cnt[out$values == ''] <- 0
out
#    ind   values cnt
#1 gene1      CNT   1
#2 gene2 Dis, CNT   2
#3 gene3            0
```

---

If we need the count of separate values, split the column with `separate_rows`, use `pivot_wider` to reshape to 'wide' format and use `complete` to get all the 'gene' value in 'out'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out %>% 
  separate_rows(values) %>%
  filter(values != '')  %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'values', values_from = 'values', 
     values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  complete(ind = out$ind, fill = list(CNT = 0, Dis = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  ind     CNT   Dis
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 gene1     1     0
#2 gene2     1     1
#3 gene3     0     0
```

---

Or use `table` from `base R` after splitting the column with `strsplit`

```
table(stack(setNames(lapply(lst1, function(x) 
     replace(x, is.null(x), NA)), out$ind))[2:1])
#       values
#ind     CNT Dis
#  gene1   1   0
#  gene2   1   1
#  gene3   0   0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(subj1 = c("Dis", "12", "4", "100"), subj2 = c("CNT", 
"0", "3", "105"), subj3 = c("Dis", "10", "5", "99")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("group", 
"gene1", "gene2", "gene3"))
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I am having trouble getting a tally of the number of genes missing in the two groups. The value stored in the second column is a string of comma separated group names, and I am trying to count the number of incidences of each and output a final count for each row. Since my current dataframe uses numbers instead of "dis" or "cnt" rowsums==1, which was my normal go-to isnt working. Can you recommend the correct way to do match and tally incidences in this output?

Comment: @Zoidberg_OuuuO Do you want the output as in the last expeected output in your post

Comment: Well, it does give the total number of values less than 5, (2 from dis and 2 from cnt will result in a count of 4. However, it doesnt give a separate count telling you how many low values were from the disease group (Dis=2, CNT=2) which is what my final goal is.

Comment: Looks like that final update did the trick! This is incredibly helpful akrun. I mean it, it would have taken me forever to figure out all of this on my own. I really appreciate the help!